# FileSystemWatcher can not detect the change of 1 file (add a new file), only detect atleast 2 files

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

FileSystemWatcher can not detect the change of **1** file (add a new file), only detect atlest **2** files.
The **watcher** only invoke **Changed** event in the cases:

> - Copy more than **1** files to **C:\PortViewer**
> - Copy only **1** file to **C:\PortViewer**, and I have to open **C:\PortViewer** in the **File Explorer** of **Windows**.

```
        FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        private void StartWatcher()
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\PortViewer");
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = @"C:\PortViewer";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                   | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.Changed += (s,e) => { /*Do work here*/ };
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
```

Comment: There are more events on this object, check the `Created` event.

Comment: Thank you, @LasseV.Karlsen, I found the issue. I have to use `NotifyFilters.CreatedTime` instead.

Comment: If this question isn't flagged as some kind of duplicate, you should leave your own answer and accept it so that future visitors more easily see how to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NotifyFilters.CreatedTime` is the solution:

```
        FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        private void StartWatcher()
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\PortViewer");
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = @"C:\PortViewer";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreatedTime;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.Changed += (s,e) => { /*Do work here*/ };
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
```